# String literal as the left hand side argument of 'like' operator using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Im trying to construct a query using SQLAlchemy which produces something like (in oracle):

```sql
select * from users u where 'john' like u.name || '%'
```

to get names like 'j', 'jo', 'joh' etc.

I suppose there'a something like:

```python
session.query(Users).filter(XXX('john').like(Users.name + '%')).all()
```

What should I replace XXX with?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`literal`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal) construct:

```python
session.query(Users).filter(literal('john').startswith(Users.name)).all()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think its something like this?

```
Users.query.filter(Users.name.like("%john%")).all()
```