# How to filter by "literal in column" in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

It is possible to filter by checking if a column is `in` a literal
using the `in_` column operator of SQLAlchemy - [doc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.in_)

`filter(COL.in_(1,2,3))` is converted to SQL `WHERE COL IN (1, 2, 3)`
which filters by checking if a column is `in` a literal

I am searching for a way to filter by checking if a literal is `in` a column, where the column is of type array (or repeated field in BigQuery)

Is there an SQLAlchemy construct in which it is possible to create a filter similar to the following SQL (BigQuery Standard)

```
WHERE 1 in UNNEST(COL)
```

A very similar query in PostgreSQL and the expected results can be seen [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mUTWMbFapc3cLxcbvzUDZ6/0)

Comment: what is the behaviour you are getting with in_ operator and how does it deviate from what you would like to achieve?

Comment: The `in_` operator can only be used on a column to my understanding.
and thus i can only create SQL similar to the first SQL snippet
`WHERE COL IN (1, 2, 3)`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072976/string-literal-as-the-left-hand-side-argument-of-like-operator-using-sqlalchem and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165371/sqlalchemy-use-psqls-operator-when-string-is-on-left-and-column-on-right

Comment: you can use the in_ operator directly the way you would in SQL (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603088/sqlalchemy-in-clause)